# 3G Wi Fi роутер

Tags: wifi, роутер

Возможно кто-то уже сталкивался с подобным вопросом, итак:

Есть вот такая "игрушка" [huawei e355](http://www.huaweidevice.com/worldwide/productFeatures.do?pinfoId=3254&treeId=3619&directoryId=5009&tab=0), в описании сказано, что можно подключить внешнюю антенну. Как я понимаю, речь идет об антенне для 3G сигнала с CRC9 разъемом.

Есть ли какие-то переходники для подключения туда же еще и wi-fi антенны?

Суть в том, что нужно спрятать модем в железный короб и вывести антенны наружу.

P.S. Да да, интернет был вылизан дальше некуда и пока ничего дельного я не нашел.Если есть какие-то альтернативные решения - буду только рад, главное условие, чтобы модем был с USB портом, а не через miniUSB провод подключался.

Comment: Вопрос все еще актуален :)

Comment: А какая конечная цель? Какая разница, на проводке или свисток, если вы его в железный короб прятать будете?

Comment: Сделаю уточнение:Мы работаем над светодиодными лампами для складов(огромные расстояния), задача - управлять лампой по "воздуху", в нашем случае и wi-fi, и 3G. Что-то вроде такой штуки - http://www.nst.na.by/images/sku-80_large.gif Вот все управление и прячется внутрь, сигнал есть, но плохой, нужно усилять. Внешние антенны улучшают ситуацию, но вопрос в том, можно ли использовать 1 антенну для 2х сигналов, учитывая что частотный диапазон 3G и wi-fi почти одинаковый.

Comment: А это так, до кучи: http://bester-ltd.ru/product/n211-crc9-121-rg178/ (это переходник).

Comment: знаю, видел, спасибо, но это не совсем то, что надо (:

Answer (score 1):

В смысле - всё железо спрятать в короб, а наружу - внешние антенны? Да, можно, и WiFi внешние тоже есть.

3G: [Антенна для 3G модема, внешняя антенна для 3G модема, самодельная антенна для 3G USB модема](http://www.qualcom.ru/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=482&Itemid=707).

Wifi: [WI-FI антенны, внешние антенны WI-FI, внутренние антенны WI-FI](http://www.qualcom.ru/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=481&Itemid=706).

Comment: Я видимо не точно описал суть "проблемы"...То, что можно подключить внешние антенны я знаю, мы их уже купили, самые дешевые, для теста. Все работает, да.Но у нас получается 2 антенны снаружи, а вопрос в том, реально ли с технической стороны, чтобы была одна антенна, но, грубо говоря, сигнал на выходе был распараллелен на два приемника - wifi и 3G модули.Т.е. возможно ли 1 один провод припаять к двум приемникам сигнала или возможно есть подобные решения и я просто их ненагуглил?

Comment: То есть - одна антенна для обоих каналов - 3G и WiFi - я правильно понял? Нет, это сделать нельзя, по крайней мере, со стандартными антеннами!

Comment: угу, именно так, одна антенна на два канала.Я понимаю, что со стандартными антеннами нельзя, использовать надо будет или готовую внешнюю, или паять самому :)Вот в этом и суть вопроса, возможно ли в принципе осуществить такое и если да, то не откажусь от каких-либо линков полезных (кроме гугла, само собой)

Comment: В принципе, диапазоны близки (2.0 и 2.4 ГГц). Разнос по частоте тоже вполне достаточен, даже для широкополосной модуляции, но помехи очень даже возможны. Основной вопрос - согласование каналов. А на этом зубы сломали даже те, кто делал антенны для космической техники (лично я в 1980-х участвовал в разработке АФАР, будучи ещё студентом МАИ). Та вот, глянь, скажем, на Луноход! Стали бы они его так антеннами утыкивать, если бы можно было сделать одну мультидиапазонную для всего железа?